# How do you tell when IIS is applying the "Default Page" setting in ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm attempting to issue a 301 redirect when a user requests http://www.mysite.com/Default.aspx to http://www.mysite.com/

The issue I'm having is that every property I can find within Request (Request.Url, Request.RawUrl, etc) is identical for those two requests.

Edit for further clarification:
This is on a shared web host, I can't install ISAPI extensions.

One more edit. Apparently the first tech support guy I talked to at the host didn't know what he was talking about, they have ISAPI rewrite installed.

Comment: +1 simply because I'm curious too.

Comment: Specifically, its SEO concerns. Having two external urls that produce identical content is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a url rewriting ISAPI filter. It's painless. [This page on Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) contains pretty much all the info you need.

Comment: I don't have access to add that filter, its a website on a shared host.

Comment: @Matt Ross: are you sure that the IIS mechanism for trying to resolve the default document by passes URL rewriting ISAPI filter?  If not you have an infinite loop.

Comment: The isapi filter would work, I've used it on other servers. Its just this one that I'm stuck on that won't let me add any.

Answer (score 2):

[Steve Wortham's Blog](http://swortham.blogspot.com/2008/12/redirecting-default-page-defaultaspx-to.html) describes how he addressed the same issue.

He used [Ionic's free Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF)

Comment: +1. The blog gives a good reason why someone would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst a lot of people cite SEO as the reason for wanting to do this, I'd just like to make a minor observation:

> [Search for the word "Welcome" on my site](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Adoodle.co.uk+welcome&btnG=Search&meta=)

This word appears on the homepage (default.aspx), and in a blog post. At the moment I'm seeing three results for this search:

[image: Search results]

The middle one is my homepage, and you'll note that it's only listed once - yet you can easily visit, and stay on /default.aspx if you browse to it (and indeed, the navigation on the site links to /Default.aspx).

If anything it's more of an issue with reporting, as google analytics for example sees /default.aspx and /Default.aspx as **different** pages (but again, the search results are ignoring casing on a windows server):

[image: Analytics repeats]

So, all I'm saying is that search engines are often brighter than SEO consultants give them credit for...

A bigger problem for my site is the fact that I have three domain names pointing at it, and still haven't gotten around to putting a redirect inplace for the other ones.

Comment: I'd call it a knee jerk response - any time the same content is available in multiple places, I'd consider it at the very least redundant and worth cleaning up.

And yes, SE's are generally brighter, but why make their job harder than necessary?

Comment: You'll also want to handle casing then ;)